# Symfony2 form submission error (setting a relation before submitting)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Here's my paste:

```
https://gist.github.com/1026584
```

The above produces the error:

```
Fatal error: method_exists(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "Proxies\JStoutMainBundleEntityLocationProxy" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /www/jstout/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 2266 Call Stack: 0.0001 622816 1. {main}() /www/jstout/web/app_dev.php:0 0.0120 1391096 2. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle() /www/jstout/web/app_dev.php:21 0.0155 1643168 3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpKernel->handle() /www/jstout/app/bootstrap.php.cache:612 0.0155 1643888 4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() /www/jstout/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/HttpKernel.php:44 0.0155 1643888 5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() /www/jstout/app/bootstrap.php.cache:416 0.0808 3808568 6. call_user_func_array() /www/jstout/app/bootstrap.php.cache:438 0.0808 3808816 7. JStout\MainBundle\Controller\VendorController->signupAction() /www/jstout/app/bootstrap.php.cache:0 0.1496 5248224 8. JStout\MainBundle\Form\Vendor\SignupHandler->process() /www/jstout/src/JStout/MainBundle/Controller/VendorController.php:55 0.1994 6163232 9. Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->flush() /www/jstout/src/JStout/MainBundle/Form/Vendor/SignupHandler.php:57 0.1994 6163232 10. Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->commit() /www/jstout/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:328 0.1994 6163232 11. Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->computeChangeSets() /www/jstout/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:249 0.1998 6187424 12. Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->computeChangeSet() /www/jstout/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:505 0.2000 6196648 13. Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->computeAssociationChanges() /www/jstout/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:490 0.2000 6221624 14. Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork::objToStr() /www/jstout/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:572 0.2000 6221752 15. method_exists() /www/jstout/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:2266
```

The error goes away if I remove:

```
$vendor->setOwner($user)
```

Is this a bug or is there a reason why I can't set the owner to a session object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have private properties in your User object ?

The php function serialize is called when inserting a object in the session, and there are issues with the private properties. You have to swith thse private properties to protected.

Comment: This was old code, but I'm sure that was one of the issues.  I'll mark your answer as the answer for now. :)

Comment: Nop, that is not the issue, I am still having the same problem even every thing is public